# Java app continuously check new rows added in table

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a scenario: we have a big table (it is split into a few small ones), I want to use trigger to track the change. We will insert rows to a tracking table if the big table has insert, update and delete event. I need to build a Java app to continuously check the tracking table to see if there are rows left there, fetch them back, do some computation, update cache and delete them. 
My question is what is the most efficient way to implement it? 
Some concerns:

- Continuous checking DB is not quite good. Maybe sleep one sec each time?
- Some rows in tracking table can be grouped together by ID. We only need to deal with distinct ID each time.
- Need to limit the return rows, maybe 200 once.

Comment: If you want to use a DB trigger why do you need to implement java code for this? Why not just use the DB triggers?

Comment: Agree with Alex Calugarescu if a Trigger will be enough then use them. I see you have mentioned about a cache, let us know what type of cache you are using.

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu I tried to only use triggers to deal with cache (Memcached), but it is not working out.

Comment: You might consider quartz scheduler for this http://quartz-scheduler.org/. Quartz will allow you to run scheduled jobs much like the *nix cronjobs, easy to setup and configure also. You can find a lot of samples on the net.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the picture here (i.e. your exact use-case). If you want to track the changes then you either need to do so in your application's data access layer (in the services that access you specific objects), either by creating DB triggers which get fired on CRUD operations. I don't see how a polling solution would work.

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu the database data is synchronized by MySQL Replication, it is updated by other systems. I can't track the change in application layer.

Comment: Then add a time-stamp column to your table which indicates the last time your table was updated (and a field for deleted), and run a task at a specific interval (depending on how many operations are performed but not every second because it will be too often), and perform your business logic...

Comment: PS: you can use Quartz Scheduler as indicated by @prajeeshkumar for your task scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you are trying to implement a queue in a database.  JMS may be a better choice.

You can periodically poll the table to find entries.  If IDs have to be groups together, I assume you need some way of knowing that the ID is complete.

If your IDS are incrementing in size, you can include the next 200 IDs in your query. e.g. `WHERE id < {id-up-to} + 200`